# Folder created but not accessible

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-10

I have installed a (older) software on a Windows 10 machine. The installer is supposed to create a folder name 'Project'. The aim of this folder is self explanatory - it is used to save/open projects created using the software. I have no issue saving or opening one of my projects using the software from this folder, however, when I browse the directory using explorer the folder is not where it is supposed to be. I tried to browse using command prompt and same result, the folder doesn't seem to exist. Since I am sure that this folder exist - since I am able to open/save to and from it - and since it's an older software, I tried to install it on a Windows XP machine and I was able to find the folder where it is supposed to be.

What am I missing? Is there a difference in the way folder are created on Windows XP vs Windpws 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a folder virtualization issue. From https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927387:

> Scenario 2: You cannot find the file or the folder that you just created
>
> When you use an application for which virtualization is enabled, you create data files in virtualizable locations of the file system. When you use another application or Windows Explorer to access these newly created files, you cannot find them. For example, if you save a file in a photo editing application in the %programfiles%, %systemroot%, %systemdrive%, or %programdata% folders, you cannot locate this file.
>
> [...] To resolve this issue, use one of the following methods:
>
> - Click the Compatibility Files button that appears on the Explorer bar to view virtualized files in the folder. The Compatibility Files button appears only if there are virtualized files in the folder.
> - Look in the C:\Users\User_name\AppData\Local\VirtualStore folder to locate files and folders.
> - Save your application's data in a folder under your user profile.